# Cluster or nginx? Cluster Stability: 1 - Experimental

Tags: node.js, nginx

Cluster Stability: 1 - Experimental

Currently I'm working with node.js. Are you guys using Cluster in production? Shall I go with nginx and run two node process in production? Please suggest.

Comment: What is you production config? Are you on a cloud-based platform like EC2 and paying by CPU? Then one way is to have two sing-core machines that has a load balancer (nginx or ELB). This way not only you have load balancing in your app when you hit your pick, but alos you can put the other machine in another availability zone so if one zone goes down the other one can survive. One step closer to the highly available application. I used Cluster on my local machine but I just don't see the reason to have one multi-core machine in AWS or RackSpace.

Answer (score 1):

I tried cluster with single node process, but didn't get much performance. :(
Did lots of trial and error with performance computing and response time. Finally fixed to work with N two-core machines in EC2. Running two node process in different ports in each machine. Configured nginx in each machine to route the requests to two node process running in different ports. Finally put all the machines under an ELB. Happy time :)

Comment: 2 years after do you still use the same architecture with AWS/node?

Comment: NO. But Nginx always there as front layer in a different system. Now we have N worker machines running node cluster having one master with multiple node workers based on cpu-count